Running single line Typescript file without transpiling
I am a newbie in TS & want to run a single line programme directly without tanspiling via ts-node
These are my specs

I ran below command
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g ts-node

This is my code
Console.log("Hello World");

I am getting below error
PS G:\New folder> ts-node "g:\New folder\Session1.ts"
(node:5020) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
g:\New folder\Session1.ts:2
export {};
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at phase4 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\bin.ts:649:14)


I am not doing any import  nothing, I think it should work without package.json file and even after adding package.json file the problem still persists....Please help me with this.
Thank You

Running into this as well. I just have a single typescript file I'd like to run without a supporting project. I've tried node 18 and node 20, both produce this same error when running ts-node on the file.

Reproduction:

I've reproduce the error you are experiencing by initializing a empty package:

    pnpm init


Then I've added typescript and ts-node packages.

    pnpm add -D typescript ts-node


Then started the script by running:

    pnpm ts-node Session.ts


Solution:
Just change ts-node to node,
It will automatically run ts-node:
    node Session.ts

Additionally you can add this in your package.json's scripts
    {
         "scripts": {
              // Other Scripts
              "dev": "node Session.ts"
         }
    }

Then you can now run your script through:
    npm run dev

It is also good practice to use camel case in naming your scripts in TypeScript/JavaScript like sessionIndex.ts.
You can also check this documentation if your TS gets larger:
https://aka.ms/tsconfig.
